# which fact about the commutation relation implies that the function is an identity

Tags: functions

We consider functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, commutation means $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

---

1. Assume that a polynomial $P$ commutes with every function. Then
   $P(x)=x$ ?
2. Assume that a polynomial $P$ commutes with every continuous
   function. Then $P(x)=x$ ?
3. Assume that a polynomial $P$ commutes with every polynomial. Then
   $P(x)=x$ ?
4. Assume that a continuous function $f$ commutes with every continuous
   function. Then $f(x)=x$ ?
5. Assume that a continuous function $f$ commutes with every
   polynomial. Then $f(x)=x$ ?
6. Assume that a function $g$ commutes with every continuous function.
   Then $g(x)=x$ ?
7. Assume that a function $g$ commutes with every function. Then
   $g(x)=x$ ?

---

Questions are mine, just for own curiosity, probably they are rather tricky then difficult, but seemed to be a little bit to tough for me to answer myself...

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your questions are answered if the following one is answered: if a function $f$ commutes with every polynomial, then has $f$  got to be the identity function?

The answer is yes. Take any $a\in\Bbb R$ and consider the polynomial $p(x)=a$. Then $f(a)=f(p(a))=p(f(a))=a$, so $f(x)=x\:\forall x\in\Bbb R$.